# Lucene .net core custom string sorting

Tags: .net-core, lucene

I want to create a string custom sorter for Lucene .Net core. How would I go about doing this? I tried following this example ([Custom sorting of null values in Lucene.Net 3.0.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40744865/custom-sorting-of-null-values-in-lucene-net-3-0-3#)) but FieldComparator and FieldComparatorSource doesn't seem to exist in the .Net Core library. I am using package Lucene.Net 4.8.0-beta00013.

--- UPDATE ---

I found FieldComparer and FieldComparerSource classes (thanks andrewjames), docs here: https://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/4.8.0-beta00013/api/core/Lucene.Net.Search.FieldComparer.html

What I need to do is sort strings. More specifically I need to sort like this:

```
data in index   wanted sort result
"1"             "k"
"2"             "st"
"k"             "1"
"3"             "2"
"st"            "3"
```

I have already done the sorter for this, so the sorting itself is done. However, I can't find any examples of an overlaoded FieldComparer sorting strings. I can only find sorting integers examples (found here https://github.com/Shazwazza/lucenenet/blob/docs-update-jan2020/src/Lucene.Net/Search/FieldComparator.cs/#L747). Specifically it's the functions Copy, SetNextReader, etc. that I do not know how to override properly. Anyone with an example of how to implement these for a string comparer? Thanks.

Comment: In case it may help: It looks like the `Lucene.Net.Search` [comparator](https://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/3.0.3/df/d91/class_lucene_1_1_net_1_1_search_1_1_field_comparator.html) classes in v3.0.3 have been renamed to [comparer](https://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/4.8.0-beta00013/api/core/Lucene.Net.Search.FieldComparer.html) in v4.8.0. It looks like the classes have also been re-worked considerably, looking at the class list (which may explain the comparator/comparer name change).

Comment: Thanks! You helped me a bit further. See the update part above.